# Pinescript loop alerts

Tags: pine-script-v5

Setting up an alert,
I was running a loop to cycle through a list of 40 assets but an alert only seems to trigger for the first asset which meets the conditions and doesn't check the rest.
I have attached the script below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='scanner', shorttitle='', overlay=true)

emaGroup            = "=== EMA ==="
ema1Len             = input.int(55, title="Fast", group=emaGroup)
ema2Len             = input.int(233, title="Slow", group=emaGroup)
emaAlert            = input.bool(true, title="Alert", group=emaGroup, inline="1")
emaFreq             = input.string( alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, title="Alert Frequency", options=[alert.freq_all, alert.freq_once_per_bar, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close], group=emaGroup, inline="1")

volGroup            = "=== Volume Change ==="
volUp               = input.float(30, title="Spike Above Average (%)", group=volGroup, inline="0")*0.01
avgLegnth           = input.int(30, title="Average Count", group=volGroup, inline="0")
volAlert            = input.bool(true, title="Alert", group=volGroup, inline="1")
volFreq             = input.string( alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, title="Alert Frequency", options=[alert.freq_all, alert.freq_once_per_bar, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close], group=volGroup, inline="1")

volaGroup           = "=== Volatility ==="
volatility_len      = input.float(title='Volatility Percentage', defval=5.0, group=volaGroup)
volaAlert           = input.bool(true, title="Alert", group=volaGroup, inline="1")
volaFreq            = input.string( alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, title="Alert Frequency", options=[alert.freq_all, alert.freq_once_per_bar, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close], group=volaGroup, inline="1")



divGroup            = "=== Divergence ==="
len                 = input.int(title="RSI Period", minval=1, defval=14, group=divGroup)
src                 = input(title="RSI Source", defval=close, group=divGroup)
lbL                 = input(title="Pivot Look Left", defval=5, group=divGroup, inline="1")
lbR                 = input(title="Right", defval=2, group=divGroup, inline="1")
rangeLower          = input(title="Min Look Range ", defval=5, group=divGroup, inline="2")
rangeUpper          = input(title="Max", defval=60, group=divGroup, inline="2")
plotBull            = input(title=" Bullish", defval=true, group=divGroup, inline="3")
plotBear            = input(title=" Bearish", defval=true, group=divGroup, inline="4")
divAlert            = input.bool(true, title="Alert", group=divGroup, inline="1")
divFreq             = input.string( alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, title="Alert Frequency", options=[alert.freq_all, alert.freq_once_per_bar, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close], group=divGroup, inline="1")


corGroup            = "=== Scanner ==="
alertFreq           = input.string( alert.freq_once_per_bar_close, title="Alert Frequency", options=[alert.freq_all, alert.freq_once_per_bar, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close], group=corGroup)

// Table Position
in_table_pos        = input.string(title="Location  ", defval= "Top Right", 
     options =["Top Right",  "Middle Right",  "Bottom Right", 
              "Top Center", "Middle Center", "Bottom Center", 
              "Top Left",   "Middle Left",   "Bottom Left"], 
     group= corGroup, inline= "2")

// Table Size
in_table_size       = input.string(title= "Size    ", defval="Small", 
     options=["Auto",  "Huge",  "Large", "Normal", "Small", "Tiny"], 
     group= corGroup , inline= "2")

corTable            = input.bool(true, title="", group=corGroup, inline="1")
bgCol               = input.color(color.new(color.gray,80), title="Background", group=corGroup, inline="1")
textCol             = input.color(color.white, title="Text", group=corGroup, inline="1")


plotHiddenBull      = false
plotHiddenBear      = false

///////////// 
// SYMBOLS // 

u01 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
u02 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
u03 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')
u04 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's04')
u05 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's05')
u06 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's06')
u07 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's07')
u08 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's08')
u09 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's09')
u10 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's10')
u11 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's11')
u12 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's12')
u13 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's13')
u14 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's14')
u15 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's15')
u16 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's16')
u17 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's17')
u18 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's18')
u19 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's19')
u20 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's20')
u21 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's21')
u22 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's22')
u23 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's23')
u24 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's24')
u25 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's25')
u26 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's26')
u27 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's27')
u28 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's28')
u29 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's29')
u30 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's30')
u31 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's31')
u32 = input.bool(false,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's32')
u33 = input.bool(false,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's33')
u34 = input.bool(false,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's34')
u35 = input.bool(false,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's35')
u36 = input.bool(false, title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's36')
u37 = input.bool(false, title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's37')
u38 = input.bool(false, title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's38')
u39 = input.bool(false, title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's39')
u40 = input.bool(false, title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's40')


s01 = input.symbol('SOLUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
s02 = input.symbol('MATICUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
s03 = input.symbol('XRPUSDTPERP', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')
s04 = input.symbol('ADAUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's04') 
s05 = input.symbol('ENSUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's05')
s06 = input.symbol('LINKUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's06')
s07 = input.symbol('DOTUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's07')
s08 = input.symbol('APEUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's08')
s09 = input.symbol('SHIBUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's09')
s10 = input.symbol('OMGUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's10')
s11 = input.symbol('AVAXUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's11')
s12 = input.symbol('FTMUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's12')
s13 = input.symbol('BNBUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's13')
s14 = input.symbol('ETCUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's14')
s15 = input.symbol('GMTUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's15')
s16 = input.symbol('ATOMUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's16')
s17 = input.symbol('DOGEUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's17')
s18 = input.symbol('NEARUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's18')
s19 = input.symbol('EOSUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's19')
s20 = input.symbol('MANAUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's20')
s21 = input.symbol('BCHUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's21')
s22 = input.symbol('GALAUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's22')
s23 = input.symbol('LTCUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's23')
s24 = input.symbol('AXSUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's24')
s25 = input.symbol('OPUSDTPERP', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's25')
s26 = input.symbol('SANDUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's26')
s27 = input.symbol('CHZUSDTPERP', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's27')
s28 = input.symbol('ZILUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's28')
s29 = input.symbol('XRPUSDTPERP', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's29')
s30 = input.symbol('WAVESUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's30')
s31 = input.symbol('TRXUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's31')
s32 = input.symbol('UNIUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's32')
s33 = input.symbol('KUCOIN:LUNCUSDT',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's33')
s34 = input.symbol('AAVEUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's34')
s35 = input.symbol('VETUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's35')
s36 = input.symbol('SUSHIUSDTPERP', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's36')
s37 = input.symbol('XLMUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's37')
s38 = input.symbol('XMRUSDTPERP',   group = 'Symbols', inline = 's38')
s39 = input.symbol('SNXUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's39')
s40 = input.symbol('CRVUSDTPERP',  group = 'Symbols', inline = 's40')


// Get Table Position
table_pos(p) => 
    switch p
        "Top Right"     => position.top_right     
        "Middle Right"  => position.middle_right   
        "Bottom Right"  => position.bottom_right  
        "Top Center"    => position.top_center    
        "Middle Center" => position.middle_center
        "Bottom Center" => position.bottom_center
        "Top Left"      => position.top_left      
        "Middle Left"   => position.middle_left 
        => position.bottom_left


// Get Table Size
table_size(s) => 
    switch s
        "Auto"   => size.auto   
        "Huge"   => size.huge   
        "Large"  => size.large  
        "Normal" => size.normal 
        "Small"  => size.small
        => size.tiny
    
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper


// Calculating
screener_func() =>
    //Volatility
    change              = math.abs(ta.roc(close, 1))
    change_raw          = math.round(ta.roc(close, 1),4)
    volatileSig         = change[1] >= volatility_len

    //Volume
    volMa       = ta.sma(volume,avgLegnth)
    volSig      = volume >= (volMa + (volMa*volUp) )
    
    //EMA X
    ema1        = ta.ema(close,ema1Len)
    ema2        = ta.ema(close,ema2Len)
    
    emaUp       = ta.crossover(ema1,ema2)
    emaDn       = ta.crossunder(ema1,ema2)
    emaSig      = emaUp ? 1 : emaDn ? -1 : 0
    
    //Divergence
    osc = ta.rsi(src, len)


    plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
    phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Regular Bullish
    // Osc: Higher Low
    
    oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
    
    // Price: Lower Low
    
    priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
    bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Hidden Bullish
    // Osc: Lower Low
    
    oscLL = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
    
    // Price: Higher Low
    
    priceHL = low[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
    hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Regular Bearish
    // Osc: Lower High
    
    oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])
    
    // Price: Higher High
    
    priceHH = high[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)
    
    bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound
    
    
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Hidden Bearish
    // Osc: Higher High
    
    oscHH = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])
    
    // Price: Lower High
    
    priceLH = high[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)
    
    hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

    var divScore = 0
    if bullCond
        divScore := 2
    if hiddenBullCond
        divScore := 1
    if bearCond
        divScore := -2
    if hiddenBearCond
        divScore := -1
    
    if not bullCond and not bearCond and not hiddenBullCond and not hiddenBearCond
        divScore := 0
    [math.round(change_raw,2),volatileSig,emaSig, volSig, divScore] 

timeframe = timeframe.period
// // Security call
[v01, vola01, ema01, vol01, div01] = request.security(s01, timeframe, screener_func())
[v02, vola02, ema02, vol02, div02] = request.security(s02, timeframe, screener_func())
[v03, vola03, ema03, vol03, div03] = request.security(s03, timeframe, screener_func())
[v04, vola04, ema04, vol04, div04] = request.security(s04, timeframe, screener_func())
[v05, vola05, ema05, vol05, div05] = request.security(s05, timeframe, screener_func())
[v06, vola06, ema06, vol06, div06] = request.security(s06, timeframe, screener_func())
[v07, vola07, ema07, vol07, div07] = request.security(s07, timeframe, screener_func())
[v08, vola08, ema08, vol08, div08] = request.security(s08, timeframe, screener_func())
[v09, vola09, ema09, vol09, div09] = request.security(s09, timeframe, screener_func())
[v10, vola10, ema10, vol10, div10] = request.security(s10, timeframe, screener_func())
[v11, vola11, ema11, vol11, div11] = request.security(s11, timeframe, screener_func())
[v12, vola12, ema12, vol12, div12] = request.security(s12, timeframe, screener_func())
[v13, vola13, ema13, vol13, div13] = request.security(s13, timeframe, screener_func())
[v14, vola14, ema14, vol14, div14] = request.security(s14, timeframe, screener_func())
[v15, vola15, ema15, vol15, div15] = request.security(s15, timeframe, screener_func())
[v16, vola16, ema16, vol16, div16] = request.security(s16, timeframe, screener_func())
[v17, vola17, ema17, vol17, div17] = request.security(s17, timeframe, screener_func())
[v18, vola18, ema18, vol18, div18] = request.security(s18, timeframe, screener_func())
[v19, vola19, ema19, vol19, div19] = request.security(s19, timeframe, screener_func())
[v20, vola20, ema20, vol20, div20] = request.security(s20, timeframe, screener_func())
[v21, vola21, ema21, vol21, div21] = request.security(s21, timeframe, screener_func())
[v22, vola22, ema22, vol22, div22] = request.security(s22, timeframe, screener_func())
[v23, vola23, ema23, vol23, div23] = request.security(s23, timeframe, screener_func())
[v24, vola24, ema24, vol24, div24] = request.security(s24, timeframe, screener_func())
[v25, vola25, ema25, vol25, div25] = request.security(s25, timeframe, screener_func())
[v26, vola26, ema26, vol26, div26] = request.security(s26, timeframe, screener_func())
[v27, vola27, ema27, vol27, div27] = request.security(s27, timeframe, screener_func())
[v28, vola28, ema28, vol28, div28] = request.security(s28, timeframe, screener_func())
[v29, vola29, ema29, vol29, div29] = request.security(s29, timeframe, screener_func())
[v30, vola30, ema30, vol30, div30] = request.security(s30, timeframe, screener_func())
[v31, vola31, ema31, vol31, div31] = request.security(s31, timeframe, screener_func())
[v32, vola32, ema32, vol32, div32] = request.security(s32, timeframe, screener_func())
[v33, vola33, ema33, vol33, div33] = request.security(s33, timeframe, screener_func())
[v34, vola34, ema34, vol34, div34] = request.security(s34, timeframe, screener_func())
[v35, vola35, ema35, vol35, div35] = request.security(s35, timeframe, screener_func())
[v36, vola36, ema36, vol36, div36] = request.security(s36, timeframe, screener_func())
[v37, vola37, ema37, vol37, div37] = request.security(s37, timeframe, screener_func())
[v38, vola38, ema38, vol38, div38] = request.security(s38, timeframe, screener_func())
[v39, vola39, ema39, vol39, div39] = request.security(s39, timeframe, screener_func())
[v40, vola40, ema40, vol40, div40] = request.security(s40, timeframe, screener_func())



// Get only symbol
only_symbol(s) => 
    array.get(str.split(s, ":"), 1)



// // ARRAYS //

s_arr           = array.new_string(0)
u_arr           = array.new_bool(0)

v_arr           = array.new_float(0)
volatility_arr  = array.new_bool(0)
ema_arr         = array.new_int(0)
vol_arr         = array.new_bool(0)
div_arr         = array.new_int(0)

// Add Symbols 
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s01))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s02))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s03))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s04))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s05))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s06))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s07))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s08))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s09))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s10))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s11))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s12))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s13))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s14))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s15))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s16))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s17))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s18))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s19))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s20))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s21))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s22))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s23))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s24))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s25))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s26))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s27))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s28))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s29))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s30))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s31))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s32))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s33))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s34))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s35))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s36))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s37))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s38))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s39))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s40))


// FLAGS //
array.push(u_arr, u01)
array.push(u_arr, u02)
array.push(u_arr, u03)
array.push(u_arr, u04)
array.push(u_arr, u05)
array.push(u_arr, u06)
array.push(u_arr, u07)
array.push(u_arr, u08)
array.push(u_arr, u09)
array.push(u_arr, u10)
array.push(u_arr, u11)
array.push(u_arr, u12)
array.push(u_arr, u13)
array.push(u_arr, u14)
array.push(u_arr, u15)
array.push(u_arr, u16)
array.push(u_arr, u17)
array.push(u_arr, u18)
array.push(u_arr, u19)
array.push(u_arr, u20)
array.push(u_arr, u21)
array.push(u_arr, u22)
array.push(u_arr, u23)
array.push(u_arr, u24)
array.push(u_arr, u25)
array.push(u_arr, u26)
array.push(u_arr, u27)
array.push(u_arr, u28)
array.push(u_arr, u29)
array.push(u_arr, u30)
array.push(u_arr, u31)
array.push(u_arr, u32)
array.push(u_arr, u33)
array.push(u_arr, u34)
array.push(u_arr, u35)
array.push(u_arr, u36)
array.push(u_arr, u37)
array.push(u_arr, u38)
array.push(u_arr, u39)
array.push(u_arr, u40)


//Volatility Value
array.push(v_arr, v01)
array.push(v_arr, v02)
array.push(v_arr, v03)
array.push(v_arr, v04)
array.push(v_arr, v05)
array.push(v_arr, v06)
array.push(v_arr, v07)
array.push(v_arr, v08)
array.push(v_arr, v09)
array.push(v_arr, v10)
array.push(v_arr, v11)
array.push(v_arr, v12)
array.push(v_arr, v13)
array.push(v_arr, v14)
array.push(v_arr, v15)
array.push(v_arr, v16)
array.push(v_arr, v17)
array.push(v_arr, v18)
array.push(v_arr, v19)
array.push(v_arr, v20)
array.push(v_arr, v21)
array.push(v_arr, v22)
array.push(v_arr, v23)
array.push(v_arr, v24)
array.push(v_arr, v25)
array.push(v_arr, v26)
array.push(v_arr, v27)
array.push(v_arr, v28)
array.push(v_arr, v29)
array.push(v_arr, v30)
array.push(v_arr, v31)
array.push(v_arr, v32)
array.push(v_arr, v33)
array.push(v_arr, v34)
array.push(v_arr, v35)
array.push(v_arr, v36)
array.push(v_arr, v37)
array.push(v_arr, v38)
array.push(v_arr, v39)
array.push(v_arr, v40)


//////////
// Volatiltiy //
array.push(volatility_arr, vola01)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola02)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola03)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola04)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola05)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola06)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola07)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola08)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola09)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola10)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola11)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola12)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola13)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola14)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola15)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola16)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola17)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola18)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola19)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola20)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola21)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola22)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola23)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola24)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola25)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola26)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola27)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola28)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola29)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola30)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola31)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola32)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola33)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola34)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola35)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola36)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola37)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola38)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola39)
array.push(volatility_arr, vola40)


///////////
// ema //
array.push(ema_arr, ema01)
array.push(ema_arr, ema02)
array.push(ema_arr, ema03)
array.push(ema_arr, ema04)
array.push(ema_arr, ema05)
array.push(ema_arr, ema06)
array.push(ema_arr, ema07)
array.push(ema_arr, ema08)
array.push(ema_arr, ema09)
array.push(ema_arr, ema10)
array.push(ema_arr, ema11)
array.push(ema_arr, ema12)
array.push(ema_arr, ema13)
array.push(ema_arr, ema14)
array.push(ema_arr, ema15)
array.push(ema_arr, ema16)
array.push(ema_arr, ema17)
array.push(ema_arr, ema18)
array.push(ema_arr, ema19)
array.push(ema_arr, ema20)
array.push(ema_arr, ema21)
array.push(ema_arr, ema22)
array.push(ema_arr, ema23)
array.push(ema_arr, ema24)
array.push(ema_arr, ema25)
array.push(ema_arr, ema26)
array.push(ema_arr, ema27)
array.push(ema_arr, ema28)
array.push(ema_arr, ema29)
array.push(ema_arr, ema30)
array.push(ema_arr, ema31)
array.push(ema_arr, ema32)
array.push(ema_arr, ema33)
array.push(ema_arr, ema34)
array.push(ema_arr, ema35)
array.push(ema_arr, ema36)
array.push(ema_arr, ema37)
array.push(ema_arr, ema38)
array.push(ema_arr, ema39)
array.push(ema_arr, ema40)



////////////
// Volume //
array.push(vol_arr, vol01)
array.push(vol_arr, vol02)
array.push(vol_arr, vol03)
array.push(vol_arr, vol04)
array.push(vol_arr, vol05)
array.push(vol_arr, vol06)
array.push(vol_arr, vol07)
array.push(vol_arr, vol08)
array.push(vol_arr, vol09)
array.push(vol_arr, vol10)
array.push(vol_arr, vol11)
array.push(vol_arr, vol12)
array.push(vol_arr, vol13)
array.push(vol_arr, vol14)
array.push(vol_arr, vol15)
array.push(vol_arr, vol16)
array.push(vol_arr, vol17)
array.push(vol_arr, vol18)
array.push(vol_arr, vol19)
array.push(vol_arr, vol20)
array.push(vol_arr, vol21)
array.push(vol_arr, vol22)
array.push(vol_arr, vol23)
array.push(vol_arr, vol24)
array.push(vol_arr, vol25)
array.push(vol_arr, vol26)
array.push(vol_arr, vol27)
array.push(vol_arr, vol28)
array.push(vol_arr, vol29)
array.push(vol_arr, vol30)
array.push(vol_arr, vol31)
array.push(vol_arr, vol32)
array.push(vol_arr, vol33)
array.push(vol_arr, vol34)
array.push(vol_arr, vol35)
array.push(vol_arr, vol36)
array.push(vol_arr, vol37)
array.push(vol_arr, vol38)
array.push(vol_arr, vol39)
array.push(vol_arr, vol40)

////////////
// Divergence //
array.push(div_arr, div01)
array.push(div_arr, div02)
array.push(div_arr, div03)
array.push(div_arr, div04)
array.push(div_arr, div05)
array.push(div_arr, div06)
array.push(div_arr, div07)
array.push(div_arr, div08)
array.push(div_arr, div09)
array.push(div_arr, div10)
array.push(div_arr, div11)
array.push(div_arr, div12)
array.push(div_arr, div13)
array.push(div_arr, div14)
array.push(div_arr, div15)
array.push(div_arr, div16)
array.push(div_arr, div17)
array.push(div_arr, div18)
array.push(div_arr, div19)
array.push(div_arr, div20)
array.push(div_arr, div21)
array.push(div_arr, div22)
array.push(div_arr, div23)
array.push(div_arr, div24)
array.push(div_arr, div25)
array.push(div_arr, div26)
array.push(div_arr, div27)
array.push(div_arr, div28)
array.push(div_arr, div29)
array.push(div_arr, div30)
array.push(div_arr, div31)
array.push(div_arr, div32)
array.push(div_arr, div33)
array.push(div_arr, div34)
array.push(div_arr, div35)
array.push(div_arr, div36)
array.push(div_arr, div37)
array.push(div_arr, div38)
array.push(div_arr, div39)
array.push(div_arr, div40)

 

// ///////////
// // Alert //


for i = 0 to 39
    if array.get(u_arr, i)
        if array.get(volatility_arr, i) and volaAlert
            volaMsg =  "Volatility on "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) + " " + str.tostring(array.get(v_arr,i)) + "%"
            alert(volaMsg, volaFreq)
        if array.get(ema_arr, i)==1 and emaAlert
            emaUpMsg =  "EMA Cross Over "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) 
            alert(emaUpMsg, emaFreq) 
        if array.get(ema_arr, i)==-1 and emaAlert
            emaDnMsg =  "EMA Cross Under "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) 
            alert(emaDnMsg, emaFreq) 
        if array.get(vol_arr, i) and volAlert
            volMsg =  "Volume Spike "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) 
            alert(volMsg, volFreq)
        if array.get(div_arr, i)==2 and divAlert
            bullMsg =  "Bullish Divergence "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) 
            alert(bullMsg, divFreq)
        if array.get(div_arr, i)==-2 and divAlert
            bearMsg =  "Bearish Divergence "+str.tostring(array.get(s_arr,i)) 
            alert(bearMsg, divFreq)



// ////////////
// PLOTS //

var tbl = table.new(table_pos(in_table_pos), 5, 41, frame_color=#151715, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))

if barstate.islast
    
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, 'Symbol',         text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = bgCol, text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, 'Volatility',       text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = bgCol, text_color = textCol, text_size =table_size(in_table_size))
    table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, 'EMA',     text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = bgCol, text_color = textCol, text_size =table_size(in_table_size))
    table.cell(tbl, 3, 0, 'Volume',         text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = bgCol, text_color = textCol, text_size =table_size(in_table_size))
    table.cell(tbl, 4, 0, 'Divergence',     text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = bgCol, text_color = textCol, text_size =table_size(in_table_size))
    
    
    for i = 0 to 39
        if array.get(u_arr, i)
            
            longText    = array.get(volatility_arr,i)     ? str.tostring(array.get(v_arr,i)) : ""
            shortText   = array.get(ema_arr,i)==1   ?  "Crossover" : array.get(ema_arr,i)==-1  ? "Crossunder" : ""
            volText     = array.get(vol_arr,i)      ? "Spike" : ""
            divText     = array.get(div_arr,i) == 2 ? "Bull Div" : array.get(div_arr,i) == 1 ? "Hidden Bull" : array.get(div_arr,i) == -2 ? "Bear Div" : array.get(div_arr,i) == -1 ? "Hidden Bear" : ""
        
        
            backColor = bgCol
        
            table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, array.get(s_arr, i),      text_halign = text.align_left,   bgcolor = backColor,    text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
            table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, longText,                 text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = backColor,    text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
            table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, shortText,                text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = backColor,    text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
            table.cell(tbl, 3, i + 1, volText,                  text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = backColor,    text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
            table.cell(tbl, 4, i + 1, divText,                  text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = backColor,    text_color = textCol, text_size = table_size(in_table_size))
```

The script above displays the scanner correctly and I have done similar scripts before with alert set ups without issue so not sure why this one is playing up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug. The super short script below also doesn't work. It only triggers alert "test 1" while I would expect to trigger 2 alerts: "test 1" and "test 2".

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test")
for i = 1 to 2
    alert("test " + str.tostring(i))
```

It is possible to trigger multiple alerts though, because this does work:

```
//@version=5
strategy("test")

alert("test 1")
alert("test 2")
```

Also, the documentation says alerts can be used both in local and in global scopes.